# RESTful Model, get rid of the id query param in the GET request

Tags: rest, model, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, restful-url

I'm a little bit stuck here. My model code is

```
Ext.define('MyFancyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/fancymodel',
        noCache: false
    }
});
```

When I try to load data by id using

```
Ext.ModelManager.getModel('MyFancyModel').load('some-id', {});
```

the request url is **/fancymodel/some-id?id=some-id** which is obviously not correct. So how can I achieve the right request url: **/fancymodel/some-id** without any patches or overrides?

**EDIT:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6peZN/)

In the developer console you can see failed GET request

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fancymodel/some-id?id=some-id
```

**EDIT:**

[Thread on the Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258809-Model-and-Rest-proxy.-Query-id-parameter-in-the-GET-request-url)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any ExtJS solution, so I have written a small patch (not sure it works in every situations) :

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Rest, {
    buildUrl: function (request) {
        delete request.params.id;
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The [standard way](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_code-section-5) :

```
Ext.define('MyPatches.data.proxy.Rest', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
    buildUrl: function (request) {
        delete request.params.id;
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have thought about that kind of patching, but maybe it seems redundant to me. I mean I'm looking for ExtJS solution. Nevertheless thanks for the answer!

Comment: I know what you mean, I think the same way. Thanks for the vote :)